UDP P2P NAT Traversal: Why Does A->B Succeed but B->A Fail
I conducted a UDP hole punching test under the following conditions:
There are two devices, A and B. A is behind NAT_A, and B is behind NAT_B. After both sides obtain each other's public IP and port, the connection can only be established if device A sends a message to device B's public IP and port first. Conversely, if B sends a message to A's public IP and port first, the connection cannot be established.
Both NAT_A and NAT_B are port-restricted cone NATs. What could be the reason for this behavior?
During my attempts to perform UDP hole punching, I send a heartbeat message to a central server while also receiving heartbeat replies from the server on both devices. This confirms that the public IP and port mappings are consistently active. Despite this, I cannot think of any other reasons why the phenomenon I described earlier occurs. Can you please help me understand this? Thank you.

I came across a blog post describing that if a NAT device adopts a policy of discarding packets from unknown addresses, then there shouldn't be an issue with establishing a P2P connection. Here, "unknown addresses" refer to addresses where your own network has not initiated outbound communication. If the policy is not discarding but rather involves a blacklist mechanism, where the NAT device adds unknown addresses to a deny list upon receiving packets, then during P2P hole punching, packets sent to these unknown addresses will be remapped to a new port because they are already listed in the deny list. This situation essentially transforms the NAT into a symmetric NAT.
To handle this scenario, controlling the TTL (Time To Live) of packets ensures that mappings are first established on your own NAT device. Subsequently, using normal TTL values to send packets ensures successful hole punching.
Following this theory, I wrote my own testing code and indeed managed to establish connections. It seems that our libjuice does not handle this scenario, which resulted in the issue I observed during testing—only when A sends packets first can the connection be established. According to the theory above, if NAT_A employs a blacklist mechanism, this would explain why if B's packets arrive at NAT_A before A's, NAT_A adds B's public address to the blacklist. Then, when A subsequently sends packets to B's public address, they are mapped to a new port, preventing successful connection establishment.
Conclusion:
Using TTL to first establish mappings within each respective NAT can avoid the situation I encountered. In my tests, I used a TTL value of 3 to establish mappings. Here is the link to the blog post where I found this information, specifically in item 11.
blog link
